# CSS responsive sprite animation

Tags: css

I have the following codepen:

http://codepen.io/AlexanderWeb00/pen/GWprqx

I am trying to make it look like a gif so that I can pause it on hover.

However the result is not as expected: it almost looks like a vertical slider but it should only behave like a gif. It needs to be responsive which it is at the moment.

It should show one full t-shirt at the time
    body {
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin: -10% auto 0 auto; /* positioning tweak */
}

.parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 60%; 
}

.children {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  background:  url('http://imageshack.com/a/img922/8632/ME6qgO.png') no-repeat 0 0%;
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: sprite 5s steps(5) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  from { background-position: 0 0%; }
  to { background-position: 0 100%; }
}
```

Comment: I could make it work with some changes to the background-position values in the keyframes: http://codepen.io/sinstein/pen/yMYgWO. Still don't have an explanation though.

Comment: that's better but not quite there, it needs to show the full tshirt